# Referencing Attributes

Tags: c#

Supposing I have this code

```
public class Class1 
{
      List<Class2> myClass2List = new List<Class2>;
      public Class1() { } 
}

public class Class1List : List { }

public class Class2 
{
   public Class2() { };

   //Class2 objects will sit in a list that is an attribute of a Class1 object
   // class1 objects will be in a list that is an attribute of a Class3 object
   // is it possible for this method to access the  list in the Class3 object
   // without passing the list as a parameter.
   public void myClass2Method(){ }
}

public class Class3 
{
    Class1List myList = new Class1List();
    public Class3(){ }

    static void Main() 
    {
        Class3 myClass3Var = new Class3();
        // do something to fill myList;
         //  added some code to maybe make it a bit less muddy
        foreach (Class1 c1 in this.Class1List){
           foreach (class2 c2 in c1.myClass2List{
           // here is where I want to reference the Class1List attribute of the
           /// Class3 object - do I need to pass the list as a paramter?
           c2.MyClass2Method();
       }

     }
    }

}
```

Now supposing I have an instance of Class2 in myList in the instance of Class3.  Is it possible for the Class2 method myClass2Method() to access myList wouthout passing the list as a parameter?

Comment: (could you explain this a little better, please?)

Comment: "Referencing Attributes"? I don't believe this has anything to do with attributes...maybe you meant "referencing properties/fields/members"?

Comment: @TimMedora Its not even that straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you dont want to.
you can add a member to class2 of type Class1List and when you add the instances of class2 to mylist you can set said member to mylist and than use the local member in the function.
**BUT** doing so is bad for you, dont do it, your deisgn is wrong and you need to ask a different question (how to design ***_*__*_*_**).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. If you think about it, Class 2 is just sitting there. It doesn't know that there is a list with a reference to it somewhere, and so can't get a reference to that list itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if a class can access a sibling. In short: No.

Classes can only access themselves and the types/values within them. Classes do not have access to the scope that constructed them (which could be considered their parent scope). Without access to the parent, you cannot access a sibling, which would be another object that just *happens* to be constructed in the same parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're essentially asking if an instance can access the list in which it is contained.  If this is correct then no, not without passing an explicit reference.  What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is add some information to an attribute of 1 or more instances of Class2.  I can either put the method in Class3, which would mean I don't need to pass the list to the Class2 object, or put the method in Class2, which I think is really where it should go, except I'd be passing the list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare

`Class1List myList = new Class1List();`

as

`internal Class1List myList = new Class1List();`

Then if class 2 and class 3 are in the same namespace then Class 2 can access it.